# CAS JPA Service Registry autogenerated tables

Tags: jpa, cas

I am using JPA Service Registry in order to register services in an SQLServer database. So, I have 3 tables autogenerated

- RegisteredServicesImpl
- RegisteredServiceImplProperty
- RegisteredServiceImpl_Props

I need to insert services manually without using cas service management webapp. But, I have no idea about the role of the two tables RegisteredServiceImplProperty and RegisteredServiceImpl_Props.

I need to know how can I insert new service using these three tables.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the CAS services API to insert services. Look at the JpaServiceRegistry.

Comment: Just I need to know  the role of each table, and how it looks after inserting a service !

Comment: One handles service defns, the others handle service properties.